# Create a query that uses string_split

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Scenario: Create a query that will output the LegID and the CarriCode where in the MCode should matched on the 3rd table. I am using string_split to individually check if the MCode is existing in the 3rd table

Sample table and data can be found here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8bd9f

The expected output is this:

```
LegID, CarriCode
1        AB
3        AD
```

since CarriCode AB and AD has an MCode of  DJM_3R, DJM_1R respectively wherein their MCode is existing in dbo.EFTest table.

My sample query looks like this:

```
SELECT L.LegID, L.CarriCode
INTO #test
FROM dbo.Leg L 
INNER JOIN dbo.[Carri] C 
    ON L.CarriCode = C.CarriCode 
    AND CType = 'H'
WHERE MCode IN (select MCode FROM string_split(MCode, ','))
```

Any ideas how can I output the correct data?

in case the sql fiddle link didnt work, I attached the DML , ddl

```
--table1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leg](
[LegID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CarriCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
[FNumber] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[MCode] [varchar](8) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Leg]
(
    [LegID],
    [CarriCode],
    [FNumber],
    [MCode]
)
VALUES
(1, 'AB', 2222, 'DJM_3R'),
(2, 'AC', 1222, 'DJM_5R'),
(3, 'AD', 1232, 'DJM_1R')

 -- table2
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Carri](
    [CarriCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [CName] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [CType] [char](1) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Carri]
     ([CarriCode],
    [CName],
    [CType])
VALUES
    ( 'AB','AB Test', 'H'),
    ( 'AC','AC Test', 'L'),
    ( 'AD','AD Test', 'H')

-- table 3
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EFTest](
    [FCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Desc] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [MCode] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
)


INSERT INTO  [dbo].[EFTest]
VALUES ('CODE', 'test', 'DJM_3R, DJM_2R, DJM_1R, AAABBB')
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me; can you please also include the DDL and DML in your question?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky already included the sample data population.

Comment: It shall be ##1-4

Comment: What is the (definition of the) type `dbo.LongName`? Also, recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using alias types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types)

Comment: Your DML statement for `dbo.Leg` is also not valid as you define `LegID` in the `INSERT` clause then then *don't* define a value for it (nor enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` if you were to be).

Comment: @Larnu, I changed it to varchar(50)

Comment: I would suggest name updates so `FNumber` is less ambiguous and describes intent instead of FunNumber or FactNumber or FunctionNumber or

Comment: Also it should be `SELECT value` in your subquery. In truth, you should **always** be qualifying your columns; if you aliased `STRING_SPLIT` (as `SS` for example) you'd get an error on `SS.MCode`.

Comment: Might as well mention this as well, as I suspect that you have been grossly misinformed on the use of `NOLOCK`: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Putting multiple values in one column where you have to constantly split them out is IMHO a database design flaw.  Better to have those as singular values in another table you join to - or perhaps even a "linking table" to do so.  Then you just use joins. FWIW string manipulation in SQL is most often not a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To account for the spaces after each comma in `eftest.mcode` you need to `trim` the result of string_split. Like this:

```
SELECT L.LegID, L.CarriCode, l.mcode
FROM dbo.Leg L 
INNER JOIN dbo.[Carri] C WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON L.CarriCode = C.CarriCode 
    AND CType = 'H'
where l.mcode IN (
                select trim(value)
                from eftest
                cross apply string_split(mcode,',')
                 )
```

The result:

```
LegID   CarriCode   mcode
1       AB          DJM_3R
3       AD          DJM_1R
```

(the third column can be omitted if unwanted in the result, it was helpful to debug the problem)

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d5805/1

Comment: Giving this credit; This works and the trim requirement further illustrates the design flaws of the OP's original database.- but that design was NOT part of the question :)